# About a generalization of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

We have that for $f$ $\in$ $L^{1}$$(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $g$ measurable and bounded on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and, for any rectangle $R$,

$$
\lim_{m(R)\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{m(R)}\int_Rg(x)dx = 0
$$

Then:

$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \int_\mathbb{R^n}g(kx)f(x)dx = 0
$$

This can be proved by solving the problem for step functions and using their density on $L^1$. What I'm trying to do is to replace the assumption. More precisely, if I have that the integral of $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is limited or, let's say, for any rectangle $R$ and a constant $M$

$$
\left|{\int_Rg(x)dx}\right| \leq \frac{M.m(R)}{1+m(R)}
$$

Does the conclusion still hold?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the **boundedness assumption** or the assumption $\frac{1}{m(R)}\int_R g \, dx \to 0$? Because the boundedness assumption is already required to just be able to write down the integral $\int g \cdot f \, dx$ for arbitrary $f \in L^1$. Furthermore, using the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, it follows that every function $g$ satisfying your second requirement is (essentially) bounded, i.e. in $L^\infty$.

Comment: PhoemueX, I'm sorry, you're right. I'm trying to replace my first assumption. Yes, it turns out that the Lebesgue differentiation theorem solves the problem. g belongs to $L^1_{loc}$ then, when we take the limit, $g(x)$ will be bounded by M. I can just replace the two assumptions and the result will still hold :) thanks!

Comment: I've edited the question.